# Not able to enter next input field - jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I am not able to type to next input field, the first field where text is being created on comma enter and its seems to be working fine but `focus` not working

Here is the code

1. Type something in first field, hit comma
2. Try moving to next input field, focus not working

```js
$('#tags input').on('focusout', function() {
 var txt = this.value.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9\+\-\.\#]/g, ''); // allowed characters list
 if (txt) $(this).before('<span class="tag">' + txt + '</span>');
 this.value = "";
 this.focus();
}).on('keyup', function(e) {
 if (/(188|13)/.test(e.which)) $(this).focusout();
 event.preventDefault(e);
});
```

```css
.form-group{float:left; width:100%; margin-bottom:15px;}
.form-group > input{padding:6px 12px; width:100%;}
.tag{background:#ccc; padding:2px 4px; display:inline-block; margin-right:5px; margin-bottom:5px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group" id="tags" >
  <label for="submittedby">Add CC</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" value="" placeholder="Add Email Address">
</div>
<div class="form-group" >
  <label for="submittedby">Other</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" value="" placeholder="Add Email Address">
</div>
```

Comment: because you are doing `focus()` on `focusout` event, which causing re focus on the same element

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to call `.focus()` on next input field, not `this`. I've got it this way: `document.getElementsByTagName('input')[1]`, but you can get it any way you like. Here is the working snippet:

```js
$('#tags input').on('focusout', function() {
 var txt = this.value.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9\+\-\.\#]/g, ''); // allowed characters list
 if (txt) $(this).before('<span class="tag">' + txt + '</span>');
 this.value = "";
  var nextInput = document.getElementsByTagName('input')[1]
 nextInput.focus();
}).on('keyup', function(e) {
 if (/(188|13)/.test(e.which)) $(this).focusout();
 event.preventDefault(e);
});
```

```css
.form-group{float:left; width:100%; margin-bottom:15px;}
.form-group > input{padding:6px 12px; width:100%;}
.tag{background:#ccc; padding:2px 4px; display:inline-block; margin-right:5px; margin-bottom:5px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group" id="tags" >
  <label for="submittedby">Add CC</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" value="" placeholder="Add Email Address">
</div>
<div class="form-group" >
  <label for="submittedby">Other</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" value="" placeholder="Add Email Address">
</div>
```

Comment: Just wondering why `this` is not working, As per your suggestion I think I can use like ` var nextInput = $(".form-control > input");
 nextInput.focus();` is this good to use?

Comment: Not exactly. You can use `var nextInput = $('.form-control')[1]` for example. You have 2 inputs with `form-control` classes, and when you write `$('.form-control')`, it will select **ALL** elements with such classes. So next you just need to select specific element (we have 2 elements, and we want to select the second), just add `[1]` after that, it will select the second input

Answer (score 2):

Simply remove the `focus()` call from `focusout` event, and it will work as per your expectation, its basically causing re focus, and you will be never able to focus out.

```js
$('#tags input').on('focusout', function() {
 var txt = this.value.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9\+\-\.\#]/g, ''); // allowed characters list
 if (txt) $(this).before('<span class="tag">' + txt + '</span>');
 this.value = "";
 //this.focus(); simply remove this
}).on('keyup', function(e) {
 if (/(188|13)/.test(e.which)) $(this).focusout();
 event.preventDefault(e);
});
```

```css
.form-group{float:left; width:100%; margin-bottom:15px;}
.form-group > input{padding:6px 12px; width:100%;}
.tag{background:#ccc; padding:2px 4px; display:inline-block; margin-right:5px; margin-bottom:5px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group" id="tags" >
  <label for="submittedby">Add CC</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" value="" placeholder="Add Email Address">
</div>
<div class="form-group" >
  <label for="submittedby">Other</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" value="" placeholder="Add Email Address">
</div>
```

Comment: Looks like your snippet doesn't work properly, the second input is not focused after entering semicolon

Comment: well, that is a designing leakage, it should be handle (focusing next) from `keyup` event just after calling `focusout()` manually. and not inside focusout. I haven't created a snippet, just copied from question and corrected where the wrong was